# Could convert data type in listbox databinding when display in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I use a float type data set as a data source to bind to ListBox, but the first field in the collection of data is DateTime data type conversion float type. Now after binding display or floating-point types, I need to bind the field the floating-point types are converted back to the DateTime type is displayed to the user, how can I do that?

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path={}}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Width="150" x:Name="lblName" Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    <Label Width="50" x:Name="lblValue" Content="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <Label Width="30" x:Name="lblUnit" Content="{Binding Path=Unit}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

this.DataContext = Collections;

The first filed is DateTime.ToOADate(); and the others are double fields that not need to convert.

Answer (score 0):

you can use valueconverter for each and every fields of your colunmns and can get required values .

for how to use valueconverter u can refer below links

http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/